# 'contains()' is unavailable: call the 'contains()' method on the sequence

Tags: swift2

How do I "Call the 'contains()' method on the sequence?"

```
 func deleteSelfieObjectFromList(selfieImgObject: SelfieImage) {
    if contains(self.dataArray, selfieImgObject) {
       removeObject(&self.dataArray, object: selfieImgObject)
       self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
let arr = [42]
if arr.contains(42) {
    print("found")
}
```